# How do I map my root object in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-mvc

I am calling

```
var BooksViewModel = function (data) {
   var self = this;
  self.Books = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, bookMapping);
}
@{ string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model); }
var data = @Html.Raw(data);
var booksViewModel = new BooksViewModel(data,bookMapping);
```

This all works great but the Books are not an array of BookViewModel that I want, it is an array of [object,object].

How do I tell the mapping to map the root object to a specific ViewModel?

```
var bookMapping = {
    'Book' :{
        key: function(book){
            return ko.unwrap(book.BookId)
        },
        create: function (options){
            return new BookViewModel(options.data)
        }
    },
    'Publishers': {
        key: function (publisher) {
            return ko.unwrap(publisher.PublisherId);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new PublisherViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
},
```

the children (Publishers) are not my issue, it is the root I want mapped to the BookViewModel from the raw data.

Comment: Your `BooksViewModel` definition has 1 input parameter, but when you call it - there is another one - `bookMapping`. Where is this mapping defined?

Comment: What's and where is `bookMapping`?

Comment: Please help us reproduce your scenario. There's still a few things missing (e.g. the actual sample data, the way you're currently constructing a root view model, an example view). We could help you best if you create a working Stack Snippet (7th icon on the toolbar).

Comment: The problem is when I call ko.mapping.fromJS, it doesn't name the root objects. The result is an array of generic objects. [Object, Object] rather than [BookViewModel, BookViewModel].  I've worked around it by using $root, but thought I'd ask if someone has a better solution.